# Create a 5 chars unique identifier from a 40 characters string

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, compression, md5

I have a list of 10 to max 300 string codes (40 word characters capitalized) that need to be stored inside an oauth2 `Access Token` (Claims based authorization); 
I have to keep the token small as much as I can (header size problem) so I'm searching a way to create a small unique identifier representing the original string inside the token.

I would then create a lookup table where I will put the uid and the original string.
When the Token will be sent by the client, through the uid and the lookup table I will get the original string back.

I've read that it is possible to truncate the first bytes of a hash (MD5, SHA1) and I would like to know if I can follow this path safely.

Is it possible to safely (collision wise) create a list of hashes (unique) of these strings where each hash would be 4/5 bytes max?

**Edit:**
I can't pre-generate a random string as a index (or just a list index for example) because this list could change and increase in size (when the server application is deployed for example and new codes are added to this list) so I have to be sure that when I get the token back from the client, the uid will be bound to the correct code.

Comment: If there are only 300 can't you pre-generate 300 random string X chars long and perform a lookup?

Comment: You haven't described this problem properly enough to answer it. You go from string to hash without explaining why. Do you mean you want to store a (small) hash of the string instead of the string itself, and are you curious whether that is collision-safe? Whether that's the case depends on what string values are possible and how you hash.

Comment: Are you looking for a hash code, or do you want some unique identifier for each string?

Comment: It is a bad idea to fit smth that is originally 16 bytes in 4 bytes just by cropping

Comment: Before using short hashes as 'unique' identifiers, be sure to read [Eric Lippert's blog post on the birthday paradox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/22/socks-birthdays-and-hash-collisions.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, any of those hash algorithms give a uniform hash code where each bit isn't supposed to carry more information than any other. You can just take any 4-5 bytes of it (as long as you take the same bytes from each code) and use as a smaller hash code.

Naturally the collision risk gets higher the shorter the hash code is, but you will still get the lowest possible collision risk for that hash code length.

#### Edit:

As the question changed; No, you can't create *unique* identifiers using a hash code. With a long enough hash code you can make collisions rare enough that the hash code can be used as a unique identifer for almost any practical application, but a 32 bit hash code doesn't do that, a 128 bit hash code would do that.